# When is a `value_type` of an iterator used?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, semantics

I am trying to understand when an `iterator::value_type` is actually used.

Because, all operators of iterators, seem to use only `iterator::pointer` and `iterator::reference`.

**Question:** Is `iterator::value_type` actually used for something?

**Extra question:** Would an iterator inherited from

```
std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int, std::ptrdiff_t, bool*, bool&>
```

raise some semantic issues?

**EDIT:** To understand why I am asking this question, it's because I am working on an iterator for a type for which `pointer` and `reference` are proxy classes.

Comment: Regarding the EDIT, in that case it's certainly useful to have `value_type` as a separate `typedef`, since `remove_reference_t<decltype(*begin)>` is not of the type of the underlying value anymore, but has the type of the proxy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of using it in generic code. Suppose you're writing a generic function that sums up a range in C++11. You can write it as

```
template<typename It>
auto sum(It begin, It end) -> typename It::value_type
{
    typename It::value_type _sum{}; 
    // compute the sum
    return _sum;
}
```

<del>Of course you can use `decltype(*begin)` instead, but using `value_type` looks neat-er and more elegant.</del> In C++14 I cannot think of a really good use, since you can have auto type deduction on function return.

**EDIT** As mentioned by @Luc Danton in the comment, using `decltype(*begin)` yields a reference most of the time, so you'd need to `std::remove_reference`, which makes it look quite nasty. So `value_type` comes handy.

Comment: If `It` is e.g. `std::vector<int>::iterator`, then `decltype(*begin)` is `int&` which corresponds more to `reference` than `value_type`.

Comment: @LucDanton And it's not even guaranteed to return the value type, since in principle an iterator may be implemented via proxies, not necessarily pointers.

Comment: Note that when I said `reference` I meant `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference`, which needs not be a reference type (confusingly enough). It corresponds to the type of `*it` (for an appropriate `it`), hence the relation to `decltype(*begin)`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I also realized that and that's why I also commented on the proxy version, in which case the reference is just a proxy in which you write via the `operator=`.

Comment: Using `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` seems better than `It::value_type` as it handles pointers too.