# Is std::span a valid iterator::reference type?

Tags: c++, reference, iterator

I have trouble finding the semantics of the `reference` type trait of an iterator. Let's say I want to implement a chunk iterator, that, given a position into a range, will give me chunks of that range:

```
template<class T, int N>
class chunk_iterator {
  public:
    using reference = std::span<T,N>;

    chunk_iterator(T* ptr): ptr(ptr) {}

    chunk_iterator operator++() { ptr += N; return *this; }
    reference operator*() const { return {ptr,N}; }
  private:
    T* ptr;
};
```

The problem that I see here is that `std::span` is a view-like thing, but it does **not** behave like a reference (say a `std::array<T,N>&` in this case). In particular, if I assign to a `span`, the assignement is shallow, it will not copy the value.

Is `std::span` a valid `iterator::reference` type? Are `view` and `reference` semantics explained in detail somewhere?

What should I do to solve my problem? Implement a `span_ref` with proper `reference` semantics? It it already implemented in some library? Is a non-native `reference` type even allowed?

(note: solving the problem by storing a `std::array<T,N>` and returning a `std::array<T,N>&` in `operator*` is doable, but ugly, and if `N` is not known at compile time, storing instead a `std::vector<T>` with dynamic memory allocation is just plain wrong)

Comment: What version of C++ are we talking about? Are you asking about the proper iterator concepts from C++20 (which have more relaxed `reference` requirements) or the "legacy" "concepts" from prior versions? And even then, which one? What kind of iterator are you trying to model? The relationship between `reference` and `value_type` can change based on the iterator category (input vs. forward vs. bidirectional/etc)

Comment: I think it is not related to the C++ version. I mean, yes, the details may change in C++20, but I am more interested in the general guidance to follow. E.g what is a reference? are references and views the same thing? If you think this is related to a version, let's say C++20 (it is more refined in this area). And I am thinking about forward iterator at least.

Comment: "*I think it is not related to the C++ version.*" And I think that it is, because I've read several of them and I *know* that it has changed in at least one version.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about standard-compliant iterators, it depends on several things.

For conforming [Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator)s, it almost doesn't matter what the `reference` type is because the standard does not require any usage semantics for the `reference` type. But that also means nobody except you knows how to use your iterator.

For conforming [Input Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)s, the `reference` type must meet the semantics specified. Notice that for `LegacyInputIterator`, the expression `*it` must be a reference that is usable as a reference with all the normal semantics, otherwise code that uses your iterator will not behave as expected. This means reading from a `reference` is akin to reading from a built-in reference. In particular, the following should do "normal" things:

```cpp
auto value = *itr; // this should read a value
```

In this situation, a view type like `span` wouldn't work because `span` is more like a pointer than a reference: in the above snippet `value` would be a `span`, not whatever the `span` refers to.

For conforming [Output Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator)s, the `reference` type has no requirements. In fact, standard `LegacyOutputIterator`s like `std::back_insert_iterator` have `void` as a `reference` type.

For conforming [Forward Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)s and above, the standard actually requires the `reference` be a built-in reference. This is to support uses like below:

```cpp
auto& ref  = *itr;
auto ptr   = &ref;             // this must create a pointer pointing to the original object
auto ref2  = *ptr;             // this must create a second, equivalent reference
auto other = std::move( ref ); // this must do a "move", which may be the same as a copy
ref        = other;            // this must assign "other"'s value back into the referred-to object
```

If the above didn't work correctly, many of the standard algorithms wouldn't be possible to write generically.

Speaking to `span` specifically, it acts more like a pointer than a reference logically. It can be re-assigned to point to something else. Taking its address creates a pointer to the `span`, not a pointer to the container being spanned over. Calling `std::move` on a span copies the span, and doesn't move the contents of the spanned range. A built-in reference `T&` will only refer to one thing ever once it's been created.

Creating a non-conforming `reference` that actually works with standard algorithms would involve a family of types overloading `operator*`, `operator->`, and `operator&`, `operator=`, and `std::move`, and modeling pointers, lvalue references, and rvalue references.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of an iterator's `reference` type cannot be understood without comprehending its relationship to the iterator's `value_type`. An iterator is a construct that represents a position within a sequence of `value_type`s. A `reference` is a mediator within this paradigm; it is a thing that acts like a `value_type (const) &`. Until you figure out what your `value_type` is going to be, you can't decide what your `reference` will need to look like.

What "acts like" means depends on what kind of iterator we're talking about.

For C++11, the InputIterator category requires that `reference` be a type which is implicitly convertible to a `value_type`. For the OutputIterator category, `reference` is required to be a type which is assignable *from* a `value_type`.

For all of the more restricted iterator categories (ForwardIterator and above), `reference` is required to be *exactly* one of `value_type &` (if you can write to the sequence) or `value_type const &` (if you can only read from the sequence).

Iterators where `reference` is not a `value_type (const) &` are often called proxy iterators, as the `reference` type typically acts as a "proxy" for the actual data stored in the sequence (assuming the iterator isn't just inventing values to begin with). Proxy iterators are often used for cases where the iterator doesn't iterate over a range of actual `value_types`, but simply pretends to. This could be the bitwise iterators of `vector<bool>` or an iterator that iterates over the sequence of integers on some half-open range [0, N).

But proxy iterator `reference`s have to act like language references to one degree or another. InputIterator `reference`s have to be implicitly convertible to the `value_type`. `span<T, N>` is not implicitly convertible to `array<T, N>` or any other container type that would be appropriate for a `value_type`. OutputIterator `reference`s have to be assignable from `value_type`. And while `span<T, N>` may be assignable from an `array<T, N>`, the assignment operation doesn't have the same *meaning*. To assign to an OutputIterator's `reference` ought to change the values stored *within* the sequence. And this doesn't.

In any case, you first need to invent a `value_type` that does what you need it to do. Then you need to build a proper `reference` type that acts like a reference. Lastly... well, you can't make your iterator a ForwardIterator or higher, because C++11 doesn't support proxy iterators of the most useful iterator categories. C++20's new formulation of iterators allows proxy iterators for anything that isn't a `contiguous_iterator`.

Comment: Ah you are totally right. My mistake. I mean NOT like a reference, and this is what I explained just in the sentence after. Corrected -_-

Comment: Can you link to where it says the `reference` requirements are relaxed for 20?

Comment: @ZuodianHu: Not really. C++20's iterator language concepts involve literally dozens of sub-concepts using byzantine connections and so forth; there's not really one thing I can link you to. Just read through the [iterator concepts section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.concepts) and start following the rabbit holes.

Comment: Silly question: could `value_type` be `std::span`? It does not have ownership but it is regular...

Comment: @Bérenger: Will assigning to a `span` change the contents of the sequence? Only if the iterator is over a literal sequence of `span`s, like a `vector<span>` or something.

Comment: No, I mean in the general case. For instance, in my example, lets say I have a `vector<int>` and I want to iterate over chunks. Then `value_type = span<int>` would make sense I think.

Comment: I mean, what else? It seems to me that `value_type` is not really useful anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115615/when-is-a-value-type-of-an-iterator-used

Comment: @Bérenger: `value_type` is a *promise*. It's a promise that the iterator is expected to fulfill. If I create an object of `value_type`, and your iterator is writable to its values, then I have the right to assign this object to any `reference` I am given, and this assignment will assign to the stored value appropriately. Similarly, I have the right to convert any `reference` I am given to a `value_type`.

Comment: Yes I understand that. My question is: does `value_type = std::span<int>` breaks that promise if `reference = span_ref<int>` with `span_ref` having `operator=` copy/moving the underlying values  and convertible to `std::span`?